# How can I delete all the files in the current directory except one file?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to delete all the files in the current directory but I want to keep one file (update.bat)

I have this script:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do if not '%%~ni' == 'update.bat' del %%i
```

It is not working as expected because it deletes all the files and the condition seems not to be take into consideration.

What is the problem in my script?

Comment: Because the `n` modifier is the file name without the extension.  Open up a cmd prompt and type `FOR /?` to read what all the modifiers do. If you are watching the batch file execute you should be able to see the for variable expand to file name only.  Also a `FOR /R` walks the directory tree.  If you just want the current directory then remove the `/R`.

Comment: Did you consider creating following script? `for /r %%i in (*) do echo '%%~ni'`. This might show you what your script is doing, you'll learn a lot from it :-)

Comment: You seem to be competent programmer in other languages so I hope you take @Dominique's advice and learn to properly debug your batch files like you would with any other language you program in.  If you would have just looked at the output from the commands and read the help file for the command you were using, you could have solved the issue yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one thing: if your file is called `update.bat`, %%~ni will return `update` as `~n` returns only the name but not the extension. So you are checking `update==update.bat` which is false. Further, `del %%i` might cause problems if your path contains spaces. You should also avoid spaces where they are not needed. However, replace `%%~ni` with `%%~nxi` to get the name **and** extension and your code will work:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do if not '%%~nxi' == 'update.bat' del %%i
```

But this code is "cleaner":

```
for /r %%i in (*) do if not "%%~nxi"=="update.bat" del "%%i"
```